# Separate solution into different projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm currently learning ASP.Net MVC; I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 with MVC4 (which is the last version) and I'm totally new to this stuff. My goal is to rewrite a huge web application to MVC, so I was told to separate my main solution into 3 projects using the code-first method:

- The core (models and controllers I guess)
- The UI (views, scripts, and Content)
- And the Database (Entity Framework 5.0 will be used)

I'm quite familiar with MVC, but not separating stuff into different projects. Now I'm a bit lost, I don't have a clue on how to do that, which should reference who, where, how, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with the edits here. I've restored the original question. Marking words such as MVC as code isn't right, and the original question's use of + already appears properly as an item list.

Comment: @David Scoresby, i can send you a pdf for this requirement.so can u give me your email id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution could be structured this way:

1. UI - ASP.NET MVC application project containing the controllers, views, view models, mapping logic between your domain models and view models, scripts, styles, ...
2. DAL (EF 5.0, EF autogenerated domain models, Data Contexts, ...) everything that is specific to the data retrieval

The UI layer will then reference the DAL layer.

Some people might also opt to externalize the controllers, view models and mapping logic into a third layer which in turn will reference the DAL layer. The UI layer in this case will reference both other layers.

Comment: My question now is HOW to do that, I mean what folders to move/not move (global, app_start for instance), what project should reference the other, etc...

Comment: You start with an Empty ASP.NET MVC project template. This way you don't need to be moving anything out because nothing will exist. You add a second project of type class library to your solution in which you put all your EF specific stuff. Then you have the ASP.NET MVC application project reference the class library containing your DAL logic. Then you could start adding controllers in your main project.

Comment: Thanks, what now if I want to move my views, content and script to another project (as I said, in the end I want a UI project, a core project, and a DAL project - which you just explained)

Comment: You should not move your Views, Content and Script folders. They must be part of your ASP.NET MVC project. You could move your Controllers and View Models into a third project if you want. Then the ASP.NET MVC project will reference both the DAL and Core projects. The Core project will reference only the DAL project.

Comment: Things are getting more clear. Now how do I tell my UI project (the ASP.NET MVC one) that his controllers and models are located in another project? Does my controller/model project has to be ASP MVC? Thanks for your help

Comment: You don't need to tell it anything. By default the ASP.NET MVC controller factory will look for public classes deriving from Controller in all referenced projects. So for example assuming you have kept the default routes, when a user attempts to navigate to `/home/index` ASP.NET MVC will look for a public class names `HomeController`. If you have referenced the Core project in your ASP.NET MVC project it will find it, instantiate it and use it. As far as the view models are concerned, since they are used by your controllers you still don't need to explicitly configure anything specific.

Comment: It seems to be working fine, the only problem is that you can't right click -> add controller/view as easily as before, but that's ok. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In order to preserve some typical VS Web Project functionalities, you can create your *child* projects starting from an **empty ASP.NET MVC** template (instead of a *class library* one), and then delete some unwanted files. See [this blog post](http://bob.archer.net/content/aspnet-mvc3-areas-separate-projects)

Answer (score 0):

There are tutorials available on here: http://www.asp.net/mvc
It really helped me out to get the basics of MVC, but be aware - sometimes there are parts missing in the video's, but you can find the code which isn't provided easily elsewhere.

Good luck :)

The tutorials are used to show code first.

Comment: The problem with these tutorials is that they use the basic MVC structure provided by Visual Studio, which I'm not going to use.

Answer (score -1):

create an empty solution using the Visual Studio Blank Solution template

add a solution folder (folder name will be your project name)

then right click that folder and select add project then select "class library" (for The c# classes domain logic)

same again right click the folder and select add project then select asp.net mvc3 template

then same way you create the test template as a new project.

For more information you can follow this book http://www.apress.com/9781430234043

Comment: That link appears to be a thankfully no longer working unauthorised download of a commercial book. If it's legitimate, please clarify.